# Deserialize json string using datacontract serializer in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractserializer

Below code is used for deserializing json string from URL

```
string s = "http://stgxx.xxapixx.xyxxxz.com/data/statistics.json?apiversion=5.4&passkey=xyxxx&filter=productid:test1&stats=NativeReviews";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())  
{
   string s1 = wc.DownloadString(s);

   byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1);
   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

   DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BVJSONRatings));
   stream.Position = 0;

   BVJSONRatings yourObject = (BVJSONRatings)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}
```

This is the json response format

```
{
"Errors": [], 
"HasErrors": false, 
"Includes": {}, 
"Limit": 10, 
"Locale": "en_US", 
"Offset": 0, 
"Results": [
    {
        "ProductStatistics": {
            "NativeReviewStatistics": {
                "AverageOverallRating": 5, 
                "OverallRatingRange": 5, 
                "TotalReviewCount": 1
            }, 
            "ProductId": "test3", 
            "ReviewStatistics": {
                "AverageOverallRating": 3.8333, 
                "OverallRatingRange": 5, 
                "TotalReviewCount": 6
             },
     }        
], 
"TotalResults": 1
}
```

I'm using the below objects to map the above json to them

```
 public class BVJSONRatings
{
    public string ProductId;
    public string AverageOverallRating;
    public string TotalReviewCount;
    public string TotalResults;
    public IList<Results> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public IList<ProductStatistics> ProductStatistics { get; set; }
    public IList<string> ReviewStatistics { get; set; }
}

public class ProductStatistics
{
    public string TotalReviewCount;
    public string AverageOverallRating;
}
```

In the process of deserializing I'm not getting the values within "Results" all I get is just "TotalResults": 1.

Comment: The JSON you posted is invalid and your classes are not even close to what they should be to map the JSON on. Also it's **not** a good idea to share keys in your post, like the `passkey`

Comment: @Jim  passkey values are not real ones.

Comment: That is a good thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the only object that corresponds with your JSON. You have to use `[JsonProperty("propertyName")]` for each attribute.

And since your object contains a list of results, your `Results` should look like this: `IList<Results> Results { get; set; }`

Your class could look like this:

```
public RootObject()
{
    [JsonProperty("HasErrors")] //This will point to your JSON attribute 'HasErrors'
    public bool Errors { get; set; } //Note that the name is different, but it will still deserialize.

    [JsonProperty("Limit")]
    public int Limit { get; set; }

    public IList<Results> Results { get; set; }
    //Etc...
}
```